# Is it possible to have multiple 'if/elif' statements but only one result?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get multiple if/elif statements to give one result? 
Example:

```
action = input ("would you like to walk or run? ")
```

how would I then be able to make multiple answers, such as "run" or "Run" give me the same result without having to copy/paste the code for ever if/elif statement? Can I write the code to use multiple 'if' statements to give the one result?

Comment: I know that for the "run"/"Run" example I could set the answer to  "Run" with run.capitalize(), but I want to be able to apply this to more that different capitalization.

Answer (score 7):

Just change the case of your `action` while comparing with your target

```
if action.lower() == "run":
```

Alternatively, if your conditions are not as simple as you depicted, you can either use @Tim's solution or better use a dictionary lookup

```
action_item = {
'run':do_it_fast
'sprint':do_it_fast
'amble':do_it_slowly
'walk':do_it_slowly
'default':do_default
}

action_item.get(action.lower(), 'default')()
```

**Note** Its subjective, but but my experience reading and maintaining the dictionary instead of multiple if-then with list of tuples is easier.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, I'd go with @Abhijt's (first) answer. In the general case, to allow several different strings, you can do something like:

```
if action in ("run", "sprint"):
   do_it_fast()
elif action in ("amble", "walk"):
   do_it_slowly()
```

Comment: @Abhijit Unless you store that set somewhere globally so you can access it directly, the creation of the set is significantly slower than creating a tuple *and* looking up the value. Especially for tuples of this size, the O(1) lookup speed from sets does not matter.

Comment: @poke In Python 3.2+, the use of a set is optimized and isn't slower any more. http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you can use `in` to test whether their result is in a sequence:

```
if action in ('Run', 'walk really quickly', 'sprint like hell'):
```

Answer (score 1):

A single if can check a single boolean expression. And a single boolean expression can be composed of multiple individual expressions. In your case, if you want multiple different values for `action` to have the same result, you can just use `or` to concat multiple tests:

```
if action == 'run' or action == 'Run' or action == 'walk fast':
    # run here
```

As Abhijit already mentioned, you can also normalize `action` to skip some tests. For example making all characters lower case characters using `str.lower` or stripping all whitespace using `str.strip`:

```
if action.lower().strip() == 'run' or action.lower().strip() == 'walk faster':
    # run here
```

As you can see, it makes sense there to do that normalization before entering the if statement, so you don’t have to repeat it:

```
action = action.lower().strip()
if action == 'run' or action == 'walk faster':
    # run here
```

And finally, if all you’re doing is string equality comparisons, you can also use the `in` operator, to check if your `action` is within a list of valid expressions for this action:

```
action = action.lower().strip()
if action in ('run', 'walk faster'):
    # run here
```